# How to efficiently use binning and intervals in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply, intervals

## Background

I have created a model, of sorts.  More accurately, standard machine learning models were performing very poorly for my data set, so I went "old school" and simply binned my numerical values and calculated the mean of each of these variables.  I now want to "predict" using this binned data set.

My "model" dataset looks something like this:

```py
    binnedYearOfBuild   binnedGross         binnedNet       Average
0   (1950.999, 1995.0]  (24.999, 916.0]     (5.999, 332.0]  11700.00
1   (1950.999, 1995.0]  (24.999, 916.0]     (5.999, 332.0]  68520.00
2   (1950.999, 1995.0]  (24.999, 916.0]     (5.999, 332.0]  70890.00
3   (1950.999, 1995.0]  (24.999, 916.0]     (5.999, 332.0]  44306.25
4   (1950.999, 1995.0]  (24.999, 916.0]     (5.999, 332.0]  26640
```

## Prediction Data

But each of those are intervals except for the average. My data will have actual values, like this:

```py
    YearOfBuild     Gross   Net
100     2010.0      19128.0     9736.0
200     2008.0      16162.0     6128.0
300     2009.0      792.0       0.0
400     2009.0      792.0       0.0
500     2009.0      8273.0      4002
```

## Problem: Checking those intervals is very slow

I cannot figure out an efficient way to ask which row of the model each row of new data belongs to.  I did something like this:

```py
def check_binned_cols(row, val):
    # 3 because there are 3 binned cols
    for idx in range(3):
        if val[idx] not in row[idx]:
            return False
    return True
```

and then:

```py
any(model_df.iloc[:,:3].apply(check_binned_cols, axis='columns', args=(predict_row,)))
```

where `predict_row` is a row in the prediction dataset that I want to check.

This is incredibly slow, and that does not surprise my; I have a for loop thrown inside a function that is getting called by `pd.apply`.  But I cannot seem to find some pre-made function that can do what I'm asking. This seems hard to believe, since I am just trying to check to see if a value falls within a pandas bin interval.

How can this be done better (faster)?

Comment: How did you create the bins? Did you use `pd.cut/qcut`? You can probably apply `pd.cut` to the test data passing the bin limits, then pass it to the model.